# FTP connetion gets terminated on file upload

Tags: ftp, filezilla

The same problem occurs in all the FTP clients I've tried. And I don't have a firewall set up on my computer or router.

When connecting to an FTP server and uploading a file, the connection stalls after the transfer hits 100% and then the connection to the server closes.

The file does get uploaded in it's entirety so it seems like the client isn't ending the transfer when it's done.

*(Domain and IP's below have been edited)*

The FTP servers I've had this problem with are all One.com servers.

I've talked with their support and we determined that the problem was on my end.

---

I tried using the `ftp` command in windows:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ftp ftp.example.com
Connected to ftp.example.com.
220 Welcome to One.com FTP.
500 'OPTS': command unrecognized.
User (ftp.example.com:(none)): example.com
331 User example.com OK. Password required
Password:
230-User example.com has group access to:  2810660
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
ftp> cd test
250 OK. Current directory is /test
ftp> lcd F:\xampp\htdocs\example
Local directory now F:\xampp\htdocs\example.
ftp> put index.php
200 PORT command successful.
150 Connecting to port 56694
Connection closed by remote host.
ftp>
```

And Filezilla:

```
Status: Resolving address of ftp.example.com
Status: Connecting to 0.0.0.0:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Resolving address of ftp.example.com
Status: Connecting to 0.0.0.0:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Connected
Status: Starting upload of F:\xampp\htdocs\example\index.php
Command:    CWD /
Response:   250 OK. Current directory is /
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is your current location
Command:    TYPE A
Response:   200 TYPE is now ASCII
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,247,194).
Command:    STOR index.php
Response:   150 Accepted data connection
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  File transfer failed
Status: Disconnected from server
```

The file transfer in this test only took like half a second. It's a 2040 byte file...

So the timeout is not due to that.

All other actions on the FTP server seem to work fine.

As it is now I have to upload one file at a time and stop FileZilla from trying to re-upload the file since the connection dropped. And then do the next file and so on...

Comment: If you are running a local software firewall, does disabling it have the ftp client exhibit the same error?

Comment: I don't have a firewall installed and the windows firewall is disabled. I've also disabled my routers firewall.

Comment: The odd thing is that it works for others just fine and it works on my computer at work. Just my home computer that's being annoying.

Comment: So the *"Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity"* message is wrong? As you claim that the transfer *"took like half a second"*.

Comment: In FileZilla you can see the transfer progress and the transfer instantly hits 100% and then stalls untill the 20 second timeout as is default in FileZilla. The File is properly uploaded though... Even if I increase the timeout  to 60 seconds it's the same, just takes longer for it to time out.